# date_popup element not working when the form is rendered with ajax

Tags: 7, ajax, datetime

How to attach javascripts to form rendered with ajax?

In particular, I have problem with popup calendars in my form. They are not showing, when my form is rendered with ajax.

I am rendering form with javascript as follows:

```
$.get('/event-form', {}, function(data) {
$('#event-popup-container').html(data);
```

This code calls ajax callback "/event-form". returned variable 'data' containes my form. This form is displayed on web page in HTML element $('#event-popup-container'). It works OK, just date_popup elements in form don't show popup calendars. Propably I  have to attach some javascripts somehow, when the form is not loaded with page load, but with ajax call. But I have no clue how.

I have such a code in my menu callback of path '/event-form':

```
<?php  
  //...
  $event_form = drupal_get_form('ef_event__form', $event_id, NULL);
  $output .= drupal_render($event_form);
  drupal_json_output($output);
?>
```

Can anybody help, how to make work all needed javascripts, when the form is loaded with ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using any of AJAX helpers provided by Drupal. When you are using [Form API AJAX](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax), for example, all [behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) are re-initialised and functionalities like calendar added to new elements.

If you are not using Drupal-provided AJAX functionality, you need to manually call all [behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) with a proper context after your request is finished and DOM tree updated, probably by calling

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors(element)
```

on added DOM element.

Comment: thanks. Now I know where I have to place additional code. But I don't know what I should place there. Is there any general method to ad dall needed javascripts for some form element or should  I study date_popup source code and find it there?

Comment: @tomas.teicher All functions you need to re-execute are attached to `Drupal.behaviors`. Just loop over them and call them all.

Comment: thank you. Your answer works. But I am not sure whether it is needed to call all behavior's functions. As it is written in this thread https://drupal.org/node/1015468#comment-4227872, it is enough to add just form object as parameter. It works for me, too.

Comment: @tomas.teicher answer updated a bit. That's the best you can get from me, my experience isn't much larger than that :(